# How can i use the leaflet add control inputs in the shiny R app?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I want to make a map using leaflet in shiny with a checkboxGroupInput inside the map and use the inputs of the checkboxGroupInput to update the data that is used to make the map.
But I don't know how to use those inputs, I tried the code below but it didn't work.
I would aprecciate any advice.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)


df <- data.frame(
  cat = sample(letters[1:3],10, replace = TRUE),
  long = runif(10,60,100),
  lat  = runif(10,40,60)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  leafletOutput("map1")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet(df %>% filter(cat %in% input$x))%>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(~long,~lat) %>%
      addControl(checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'x',
                                    'Select cat',
                                    unique(df$cat)))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simpler to use a layer control using `addLayersControl`. You only need to set the `group` parameter of `addMarkers` with the column `cat` of your data frame. Finally, set the parameter `overlayGroups` of `addLayersControl` with the unique values of column `cat`.

```R
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

df <- data.frame(
  cat = sample(letters[1:3],10, replace = TRUE),
  long = runif(10,60,100),
  lat  = runif(10,40,60)
)

ui <- fluidPage(  
  leafletOutput("map1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(df)%>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(~long, ~lat, group = ~cat) %>%
      addLayersControl(
        overlayGroups = unique(df$cat),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Using different icons per group

As is in [R Leaflet documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html), there are many possible ways to have custom icons. Below is one of them for your code. Please note that you need to provide an icon for all possible categories.

```R
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

df <- data.frame(
  cat = sample(letters[1:3],10, replace = TRUE),
  long = runif(10,60,100),
  lat  = runif(10,40,60)
)

leafIcons <- icons(
  iconUrl = sapply(df$cat, function(x) switch (x, 
            "a" = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
            "b" = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png",
            "c" = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-orange.png"
  )),
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94,
  shadowUrl = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-shadow.png",
  shadowWidth = 50, shadowHeight = 64,
  shadowAnchorX = 4, shadowAnchorY = 62
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(df)%>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(~long, ~lat, group = ~cat, icon = leafIcons) %>%
      addLayersControl(
        overlayGroups = unique(df$cat),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Geovany!! is it possible add custom markers in your solution??

Comment: I added an example of how to have custom markers.